# Importing Data Tier Application Turns Suspect After Server Restart

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, bacpac, data-tier-applications

Whenever I export a data tier application from my Azure Sql Database and then Import that .bacpac file from that export into my local Sql Server after the machine is restarted the database is marked as suspect. Before restarting the machine the database works great, but after it is in suspect mode and I've not been able to get it out.

Machine Information:

- Windows 10 (19044)
- Sql Server Express 2016

Comment: The fact that it came from a `BACPAC` *should* be irrelevant in this. What's in the error log (`sp_readerrorlog`) and how are you shutting down the server? Any chance that you have storage that is not attached properly when the server starts (like a network drive that's only attached on login), or even worse, that after creating the DB files are somehow still located in remote storage?

Comment: Well, that unveiled something, though I'm not sure what at this point. When I run sp_readerrorlog I get back an error "Failed to open loopback connection." When I look in the event log it says "The description for event Id 17052 from source MSSQLSE#RVER cannot be found". When I dig deeper I find a log next to where the sql files are stored and it has the following error "fatal exception c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION"

The system only has 1 drive that the operating system is running on, so it shouldn't be anything with accessing the drive.

I'm going to try restore from a .bak.

Comment: Upgrade SQL Server Express to a newer version.  You are several versions behind.